# Connect 2 bridge routers to my PC network adapter

Tags: networking, bridge-router

My Windows 10 PC receives internet from a distant wifi router, using its wireless adapter. Also it needs to communicate individually with 2 distant wifi cameras at opposite ends of a concrete building.
Question: Can I connect the PC network adapter to an ethernet switch, and then to 2 bridge routers at opposite ends of the building? Each bridge router would communicate wirelessly with its own camera

Comment: Could you provide a network diagram with your desired private IPs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, except you have the wrong terminology The "bridge router" is actually called an AP (access point) You can turn any WIFI router into one by disabling DHCP on it and ignoring the WAN port. Changing the AP's IP address so it does not conflict is a very good idea too, if required.

As a further refinement, set up both  AP units on different non-overlapping frequencies with the same SSID, password and authentication mechanism for seemless roaming betwern them.